# How to upload media to twitter from background of application without showing any UI to user except login screen once?

Tags: android, image, api, twitter, twitter4j

I have tried to visit twitter [developer website](https://dev.twitter.com/docs)
but i was not getting proper answer from there as  i tried different ways to solve this problem but i did found `TweetComposer.Builder` still i was not able to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found solution for my question i have downloaded and integrated a library from [here](http://twitter4j.org/archive/twitter4j-4.0.4.zip) with the help of this library i am able to post multiple media

**Step 1:**

first login to twitter by integrating library from this [link](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/installation.html) according to guidance

**Step 2:**

After that you will be able to login with twitter and you will get two things 1)`authToken.token` and 2)`authToken.secret` store this for further use.

**Step 3:**

```
public void updateTwitterStatus() {

    new AsyncTask() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(getResources().getString("YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"));
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(getResources().getString("YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"));

                // Access Token
                String access_token = sharedPreferences.getString("authToken.token", "");

                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = sharedPreferences.getString("authToken.secret", "");
                twitter4j.auth.AccessToken accessToken = new twitter4j.auth.AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
                twitter4j.Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

                // Update status for single image upload with raw folder
                StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate("posted from my app");
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lakeside_view);
                statusUpdate.setMedia("test.jpg", is);

                // Update status for single image upload with file
                /*String statusMessage = "posted from my app";
                StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(statusMessage);
                statusUpdate.setMedia(file);*/

                // Update status for multiple images upload with file
                /*String statusMessage = "Hey I am posting 2 images of xyz event";
                File imagefile1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/images/image_1.jpg");
                File imagefile2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/images/image_2.jpg");

                long[] mediaIds = new long[2];
                UploadedMedia media1 = twitter.uploadMedia(imagefile1);
                mediaIds[0] = media1.getMediaId();
                UploadedMedia media2 = twitter.uploadMedia(imagefile2);
                mediaIds[1] = media2.getMediaId();
                StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(statusMessage);
                statusUpdate.setMediaIds(mediaIds);*/

                // to post twit
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);
                Log.d("Status", response.getText());
            } catch (twitter4j.TwitterException e) {
                Log.d("Failed to post!", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            *//* Dismiss the progress dialog after sharing *//*
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posted to Twitter!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onPostExecute(o);
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
```

i have tried this code it works for me.